# 2018 Mac mini random restart problem

Tags: wifi, usb, thunderbolt, mac-mini, restart

Over the past couple of days, my 2018 Mac mini has been randomly restarting/shutting down after I’ve stopped using it. When I power up my Mac mini, it says that it’s been restarted because of a problem, and the report shows it has to do with something called Bridge OS 4.4? I’m not sure what that is or how it would cause a restart. My Mac mini has a Time Machine backup drive plugged into one of the two USB 3 ports, and a powered USB hub plugged into the other. I also have two 4K Monitors plugged into two Thunderbolt 3 ports, along with an external SSD plugged into another one. It’s hooked up to Ethernet, not WiFi as well. Not sure what to do here. Tried plugging the power cable in and out of the wall and the Mac mini which helped for a while, but the problem consists. I’ve never had this problem until the last week or so.

Answer (score 1):

Last week, I had a similar problem with my MacBook Pro performing uncommanded restarts. I solved it by performing a reset of the System Management Controller.

From Apple's Support page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295:

> #### Desktop computers
>
> 1. Shut down your Mac, then unplug the power cord.
> 2. Wait 15 seconds, then plug the power cord back in.
> 3. Wait 5 seconds, then press the power button to turn on your Mac.